# IBM Cloud: Have Cloud Foundry not poll for instance of application (health check)

Tags: javascript, node.js, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, discord

I am using IBM Cloud to deploy a javascript application which acts as a listener chatbot for discord.

When I deploy the code, the bot is up, but only stays up for the period of time the deploy stage polls for an instance of the bot running. In the logs I see:

```
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
```

...etc. After searching around I figured out cf was polling for a route which shouldn't exist because this application is just a listener, so I added the last line:

```
no-route: true
```

to my manifest.yml:

```
applications:
  - path: .
    name: discord-bot
    environment_json: {}
    memory: 256M
    instances: 1
    disk_quota: 1024M
    services: []
    no-route: true
```

This removes the route in the logs:

```
Removing route discord-bot....
```

However, I get the same issue where it polls, finds 0 instances, and eventually crashes with the message:

```
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 crashed
FAILED
Error restarting application: Start unsuccessful
```

As I am using IBM-Cloud, I'm unsure how to specify arguments like '--no-route' when pushing the application on the command line, but I don't think this would work anyway, as that line is in my manifest.yml, acknowledged in the deployment stage, but it still checks if the app is running.

I know I already said, but just to specify, my bot is fully functional during the time it checks for an instance. It does this for about three minutes, decides it can't find one, and crashes. If I can remove this checking process the application should work.

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand that [Cloud Foundry checks the app health](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/healthchecks.html). By default it expects a web app and polls that port, even if you do not want a route to that app. You can [configure a different health check type in the manifest file](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest.html#health-check-type).

Leave your `no-route` setting and use `process` for health check type.